What happens if I run this `set` command intended for Windows cmd prompt inside Bash in Linux?
What happens if I run this set command intended for Windows cmd prompt inside Bash in Linux?
set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;%PATH%"
echo %PATH%

In Windows cmd prompt, this modifies the PATH per my needs so I can run Git\bin\bash.exe as bash directly inside Windows command prompt.
When I run it inside Git Bash in Windows or in Bash in Linux Ubuntu, no error is produced. The command seems to run fine, but nothing happens. How do I verify what happened? Is it safe to run in Linux? I desire it to do nothing essentially in Linux, but to set the PATH in Windows.

For those wondering:
Why this? I need a single script to run in both Windows cmd prompt and Linux Bash, and this is going to be before the starting code which starts the script in both places. It has to do with my Q&A here: How to configure a preBuildSteps.sh Bash script that runs as part of the pre-build process in the MPLAB X IDE on both Windows and Linux.

Oh, I figured it out. In Linux, positional parameters $1, $2, $3, etc. can be modified via the set command. I forgot about this. So, set whatever simply sets the first positional parameter, accessed via $1, to the string whatever.
You can see that here in Bash in Linux:
$ set whatever
$ echo $1
whatever

So, set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;%PATH%" simply sets the $1 positional parameter to the string PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;%PATH%:
$ set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;%PATH%"
$ echo $1
PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;%PATH%

I remember now: I wrote about this a while back, here: How to change command-line arguments $1, $2, etc. in Bash using set --

Note: for the big picture, the above doesn't work for my needs, but this does instead: Microchip MPLAB X IDE: configure and run a shared pre-build-step Bash script that runs in both Windows and Linux as part of the build process

Bash's set is multi-purpose, but when used this way, it would not set environment variables – any non-option arguments it takes are actually placed in the shell's $1..$9 arguments (equivalent to Cmd's %1..%9).
$ echo "$1"
(nothing)

$ set a=bc def gh=ijkl

$ echo "$1"
a=bc

$ echo "$a"
(Nothing)


Perfect. Thanks. Upvoted. I just re-stumbled upon the same finding again myself. This is perfect for my needs then. I need it to do nothing in Bash.

I really don't understand your use case, to be honest. What kind of program or build config is this supposed to go into, that doesn't distinguish between operating systems?

MPLAB X IDE for PIC32 microcontrollers. Study my Q&A. I'll be updating that answer later now that I know this here. It's been quite the pain, but I have the same code and build scripts now running on Windows and Linux, in the IDE and from the command-line, and in Bitbucket Pipelines CI/CD on a self-hosted Windows or Linux runner...and this very Q&A about the set command makes the final part of this all possible.

I just rewrote this answer to make it clearer what I'm doing now.
